# moving list function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the my application to do the following. There  are 2 ordered list. One with elements and the other empty. When i hover over the firstlist next to text an image must appear and when i click the image that text must move to the other ordered list. If i click on the text nothing must happen. According to what i did when i click first time everything works properly. If i click on text i wont move and when i click on image i moves. but after that everything goes wrong. When i click image it displays twice what i select and when i click 3rd time it displays thrice what i select and after first selection im able to click on text to move it to the other list. Please help me sort out this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery_ui.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

        <style>
            #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
            #firstlist .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
            #firstlist .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
            #firstlist { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 20%; }
            #firstlist li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
            #firstlist li:hover img { display: block; }

            #seclist .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
            #seclist .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
            #seclist { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 20%; }
            #seclist li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }

            img
            {
                position:relative;
                left:232px;
                top:-25px;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table id="myTable">
            <td>
                <tr>
                    <ol id="firstlist">
                        <li>Item 1 <img src="next.jpg" id="next1"></li>
                        <li>Item 2 <img src="next.jpg" id="next2"></li>
                        <li>Item 3 <img src="next.jpg" id="next3"></li>
                        <li>Item 4 <img src="next.jpg" id="next4"></li>
                        <li>Item 5 <img src="next.jpg" id="next5"></li>
                    </ol>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <ul class = "seclist" id = "seclist">
                    </ul>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </table>

        <script language="javascript">
            //function to display the immage
            function show(id,disp) {
                if (disp == true) {
                    id.style.display = "block";
                }

                if (disp == false) {
                    id.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script>        
            $(function(){
                $( "#firstlist" ).selectable();
            });

            $(function() {
                $( "#seclist" ).selectable();
            });

            $("img").click(function() {
                $('#firstlist li').click(function(){
                    var $this = $(this),
                    text = $this.text();
                    $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist')
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mistakenly nested your event handlers. Each time you click `<img>` it is attaching a new event handler to `#firstlist li`, which will fire an event each time anything (including your `img` tag) in your `<li>` is clicked. Each time you click the `<img>` tag it attaches a new event (without clearing the old ones) and also triggers the existing attached events. This is why on the first click you get no response, the second time it triggers once, the third time it happens twice, and so on.

Try changing this:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $('#firstlist li').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text();
        $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist')
    });
});
```

To this:

```
$('#firstlist li img').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    text = $this.parent().text();
    $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist')
});
```

Comment: i alredy tried this but this didnt work. But i somehow managed to get it to work. This is how it worked

$("img").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).closest("li").text();
    $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist')
   });

Comment: Oh wait I got ya, I wasn't paying attention to the contents of the event. It wasn't getting the text from the correct place. You could also use $(this).parent().text() - updating my answer

Comment: Please mark my answer correct if you find it useful. Thanks

Comment: yeah. Thanks alot for the help. I tried to vote. but it says that i need 15 reputation for that. Again thanks for replying. Peace

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").click(function() { 
    var text = $(this).closest("li").text(); 
    $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist') 
});
```

This might work. Please try it out

Comment: yeah this is what i posted there in the comment. Anyway thanks for stopping by

Comment: oh im really sorry. I didnt notice that.